# What is a good value to seed a stdgen

Tags: haskell, prng

I need to find a good value to feed into `mkStdGen` as a seed.

The first thing I'd normally do is just use the ticks since the beginning of the epoch, however, to do that I use `getClockTime` from `System.Time`, which according to [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/old-time/1.0.0.2/doc/html/System-Time.html) is deprecated, in favour of [Data.Time](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.4.0.1). The latter doesn't seem to expose this functionality though.

Is there a better way to generate a seed for this value? Or should I just ignore the deprecation warning?

Comment: Good _for what purpose_? Otherwise I'd have to answer, [`4`](http://xkcd.com/221/).

Comment: What about [`getCurrentTime`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time/1.4.0.1/doc/html/Data-Time-Clock.html#v:getCurrentTime) from Data.Time? (I know it's not epoch time, but it provides an equivalent number.)

Comment: (In fact, [`getPOSIXTime`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time/1.4.0.1/doc/html/Data-Time-Clock-POSIX.html#v:getPOSIXTime) from Data.Time.Clock.POSIX is exactly what you want.)

Comment: @dbaupp thanks, looks like I just failed at reading the docs :(

Comment: See [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#randomness) how to use `System.Random` properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is usually unnecessary, because the [global `StdGen`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/latest/doc/html/System-Random.html#g:3) is seeded with the current time at startup. So you can just use `randomIO` and `randomRIO` and have an implicit, `IO`-based random number generator, or `getStdGen` and the usual pure functions for a more explicit one.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for `getPOSIXTime` ([docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time/1.4.0.1/doc/html/Data-Time-Clock-POSIX.html))?

**Footnote:** Please note that this **DOES NOT** return the number of ticks since the beginning of any epoch, and you should never claim that it does.  It returns the "POSIX time" which defined based on a lossy conversion from UTC time, and UTC time is not useful for determining intervals between dates without an up-to-date conversion database.